# How to put pattern lock on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

Is there a way to move or integrate the Windows 8 "pattern" lock screen on Windows 7?

I really like this locking method and would prefer to use it on Windows 7 as well.

Answer (score 1):

Eusing Maze Lock 3.0 does what you are after

It runs on; Windows XP/2003/Vista/7/8

[Download Link](http://www.eusing.com/mazelock/pclock.htm)

Comment: Are you affiliated with this product? Please disclose if you are. Also, can you provide more details on *how* the product solves the OP's problems? It's best to accompany software recommendations with more detail.

Comment: @john no I'm not affiliated with this product. Thanks for the tip about adding more details. What else is usually added when giving product details.

Comment: See [this meta answer](http://meta.superuser.com/a/5330/196392) for how to recommend software in your answer.

Comment: Thanks for the meta link . I will update when I get home